# Passing data between Node and Python using python-shell, getting errors on win 7

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x

I'm using a library called python-shell to try and send data back and forth between node and python. 
The code below should work but when I run it I get this error:

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: write EPIPE
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:712:26)
at Socket._write (net.js:731:8)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
at Socket.write (net.js:658:40)
at PythonShell.send (C:\Users\user\Desktop\node py project\fourth draft\node
_modules\python-shell\index.js:205:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\node py project\fourth draft\in
dex.js:4:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

my index.js:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var pyshell = new PythonShell('script.py');

pyshell.send(JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,5]));//the problem function

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
    // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
    console.log(message);
});

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit
pyshell.end(function (err) {
    if (err){
        throw err;
    };

    console.log('finished');
});
```

my script.py:

```
import sys, json

#Read data from stdin
def read_in():
    lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
    # Since our input would only be having one line, parse our JSON data from that
    return json.loads(lines[0])

def main():
    #get our data as an array from read_in()
    lines = read_in()

    # Sum  of all the items in the providen array
    total_sum_inArray = 0
    for item in lines:
        total_sum_inArray += item

    #return the sum to the output stream
    print total_sum_inArray

# Start process
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I think it has to do with the env path for python on win 7.

Any ideas? Library docs are located here: https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell. Also I'm on Windows 7 Node v6.9.2 Python v3.6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the parameter of python path to the script as below

```
var pyshell = new PythonShell('script.py',{pythonPath : '<path/to/python>'});
```

In this way you are explicitly setting the path to python executable command, regardless of any OS.

Here is reference of all the [available options](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell#api-reference), that can be passed to the `python-shell` constructor.

Hope this fixes the issue, if it has to do anything with the Python path issues.

Comment: Thank you! Somehow missed that option, perfect answer.